# Node.js https.request method using client credentials

Tags: node.js, https

I am trying to make a request for an access token using https.request but I keep getting the following error:

"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Missing grant type"

In the [Node.js HTTPS.Request](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) documentation there isn't any reference for how to set the grant type. I believe I need to set it in the body of the request, but there is also no reference to attaching a body to the request. I am attempting to do it with the payload variable but obviously that isn't working. I am also trying to do this request with 0 or as little dependencies as possible.

```
  function getAccessToken() {
   const https = require('https')
   const payload = {
    "grant_type": "client_credentials"
   }
  const options = {
    "hostname": url,
    "method": "POST",
    "path" : "/oauth2/token",
    "port" : 443,
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "followRedirect": true,
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>",
      "scope": "PARTNER_READ"
    },
    "payload": payload,
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }
  const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    res.on('data', d => {
      process.stdout.write(d)
    })
  })
  req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
  req.end()
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: [the spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.4.2) says `scope` should be a part of the request body, not the headers - but the documentation for the oauth flow in the API you're trying to auth with will have the final say. There is no `payload` key anywhere in the node.js docs you linked, so I'm not sure why that would work. If you don't have a firm grasp of the basics here I'd strongly urge you to just grab a dependency which will take care of all this verbosity and finagling for you, that's pretty much node's main strength - I'd recomment [got](https://www.npmjs.com/package/got)

Comment: But where and how do I state a request body in the options? In the documentation there wasn't a key for payload, body, data, content or any other key you would think would contain that data. I'm not saying the payload key is right, just looking for help on how to send data in the body. @Klaycon

Comment: The `https` docs are partial, it is stated in a couple places that everything from the `http` docs applies. [Here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback) you can see the full documentation on the `request()` function. In particular, it notes that for POST requests you should call `req.write(...)` before `req.end()` to write the request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close the loop on this, I was missing the 'Content-Type' in the header which I think was causing the "Missing Grant Type" error because it couldn't parse the body. I also needed to write the postData to the request right before the req.end(). So thank you @Klaycon for that point in the right direction!

Here is my updated code:

```
  function getAccessToken() {
     const querystring = require('querystring');
     const https = require('https')
     const postData = querystring.stringify({
         'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
     });

  const options = {
    "hostname": url,
    "method": "POST",
    "path" : "/oauth2/token",
    "port" : 443,
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "followRedirect": true,
    "headers": {
      "Authorization": "Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>",
      "Content-Type": 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      "Content-Length": Buffer.byteLength(postData),
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  }
  const req = https.request(options, res => {
    console.log(`statusCode: ${res.statusCode}`)
    res.on('data', d => {
      process.stdout.write(d)
    })
  })
  req.on('error', error => {
    console.error(error)
  })
  req.write(postData);
  req.end()
}
```